# SSRS 2016 export to excel removes new lines

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2016

devs.
I have report created in SSRS 2016 which use Tablix.
In my cell "TestBoxTEST" I added expression

```
=Fields!MyField1.Value+chr(10) + chr(13) + CType(Fields!GUID.Value, GUID).ToString
```

It looks perfect on ReportViewer, Word, Pdf even in PowerPoint...
But when I export the report to excel row is in the single line.

[image]

So far I have tried:
1) chr(13)
2) chr(10)
3) vbcrlf
4) "
" - with placeholder (as html)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Environment.NewLine in your expression:

```
= Fields!MyField1.Value & Environment.NewLine & CType(Fields!GUID.Value, GUID).ToString
```

In my example I use a two line string

[image]
[image]